# What is the etymology of 一人前?

Tags: etymology

I found this word today, and I thought it was pretty interesting. I read it in the context of "becoming and adult", or "coming of age", but I'd like to know the etymology of it. I could only find definitions for the word itself, not its origins. At first blush it looks like "one person before/ahead", but it also seems like `人前` can mean a portion of food. "One person's portion of food"? (Perhaps someone is now big enough to have an adult's portions?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The etymology is itinin + mae. I could say more about mae, but more likely you are wondering why it means this.

The key is understanding that -mae is a suffix which means:
1) an amount or portion suitable for X; sannin-mae: a serving such as food) suitable for three people
2) emphasises ones attributes or functionality; otoko-mae "manly", ude-mae "skill, prowess"

Source (seems to be popular lately): [Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%89%8D&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&index=118332200000&pagenum=1), [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%89%8D&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=1)

In itinin-mae, the sense is "a person of ability and skills", hence an adult. This is the second meaning given above. Depending on the context, the first meaning is also possible: a serving (such as food) suitable for one person.